# navigation between fragments in Java

Tags: java, android-fragments, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, fragment

I'm working with Fragments and Android studio and I need navegate in fragments from Activities. Always I get the same error "No view found for id 0x7f0800a2".

**Main Activity**

```
                    Fragment newFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    transaction.replace(R.id.nav_hotels, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                    transaction.commit();
```

**mobile_navigation**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:name="com.example.freepapp.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_hotels"
    android:name="com.example.freepapp.ui.hotels.HotelsFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_hotels"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_liked_quotes" />
```

**Fragment Home**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_home"
tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Fragment Hotels**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_hotels"
tools:context=".ui.hotels.HotelsFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Error**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800a2 (com.example.freepapp:id/nav_hotels) for fragment HomeFragment{f896362 (40055ce2-7ab7-41dd-be0b-be0edc89f01a) id=0x7f0800a2}

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The container is id of layout main activity.

```
transaction.replace(R.id.id_layout_main, newFragment);
```